# Xamarin forms : Joining main url and remaining url using IValueConverter

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have two web services in my xamarin forms project.

From the first web service, I got the main url and from the second web service, I got the remaining url of an image. The mainurl is stored in a variable using Application.Current.Properties.

The second web service is a list of items. So I need to join the two url and show it in the UI. For this, I am using IValueConverter.

My converter code:

```
public class UrlsLinkconverter : IValueConverter
   {
    #region IValueConverter implementation
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;

        string rootUrl = Application.Current.Properties["rootUrl"].ToString();
        string fullUrl = String.Concat(rootUrl,value.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine("fullUrl::>>>>"+fullUrl);
        return fullUrl.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Xaml codes:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:UrlsLinkconverter x:Key="urlJoinConverter"></local:UrlsLinkconverter>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<controls:CircleImage 
     Source="{Binding thumbnailImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource urlJoinConverter}}"
     HorizontalOptions="Start"
     VerticalOptions="Start"
     WidthRequest="50" 
     BorderColor="#1C7DB4"
     BorderThickness="2"
     HeightRequest="50" />
```

When running got a different message in the output box.

```
[0:] fullUrl::>>>>d1kv7s9g8y3npv.cloudfront.net/testsite/files/doc-lib/2017/12/26/09/26/42/141/head/tweet_pic-thumbnail.jpg
[0:] FileImageSourceHandler: Could not find image or image file was invalid: File: d1kv7s9g8y3npv.cloudfront.net/testsite/files/doc-lib/2017/12/26/09/26/42/141/head/tweet_pic-thumbnail.jpg
```

The two url are get joined but showing image file is invalid. But I can see the image if paste the full url into a browser.

I don't know the reason of this, anybody please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding http:// or https:// ? Your web browser add it automatically

Comment: change the string concat line like below:
string fullUrl = String.Concat("http://" + rootUrl,value.ToString());
Thanks